# KMeans, every run new outcome

Tags: python

I`m clustering customers using number of emails sent, cutomers open and click(CTOR) rates.
df.name is `hcps_clusters2` code and df are below

every time I run code it shows me different results. how can I fix it?

```
    Account                    Sent        or      CTOR
    0              AVG0000023   4.0  1.000000  0.750000
    4            WNLA00007135   9.0  0.222222  1.000000
    6            WNLA00010824   3.0  0.666667  0.000000
    15           WNLN00000025   3.0  0.333333  1.000000
    18           WNLN00000076  27.0  0.592593  0.000000
```

Code

```
# adjust scale
 

       max_rte_sent = hcps_clusters2["Sent"].max()
        hcps_clusters2["Sent_adj"] = hcps_clusters["Sent"] / max_rte_sent

#clustering

   

     km = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
        cluster_predicted2 = km.fit_predict(hcps_clusters2[["or", "Sent_adj", "CTOR"]])
        hcps_clusters2["cluster"] = cluster_predicted2
        print(km.cluster_centers_, "\n")
```

results after 1st run

```
array([[0.84287342, 0.3769295 , 0.1043678 ],
       [0.6692144 , 0.2586072 , 0.59702425],
       [0.1902717 , 0.44292453, 0.87663888],
       [0.29925383, 0.42937315, 0.07193657]])
```

I run same code and see different results

```
array([[0.84346118, 0.37603907, 0.10547366],
       [0.18944115, 0.44234405, 0.87673928],
       [0.29925383, 0.42937315, 0.07193657],
       [0.66629105, 0.26101668, 0.59934033]])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a param `random_state` that we could pass to this Kmeans algorithm. Set that random_state to some integer value and that would make the randomness deterministic.
The link to Kmeans:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry: it is completely normal.

The K-Means algorithm needs to start with putting the centroids somewhere in the k-dimensional space. It will keep updating the centroids for some amount of iterations. 300 by default in sklearn.

The problem with k-means is it is sensitive to the centroid starting points.

Most K-Means implementations use random centroids to avoid that.
To get better results, some people run KMeans repeatedly and use either the best result found, or centroid averages between runs.

If you look at your results, the centroids you get in the 1st and 2nd run are very close. Of course, the order of the centroids differs, because their initialization was different.

Hint: If you want to compare results, either *plot* the centroids, or sort the centroids before comparing just to make it easy to compare without making a graph.

Comment: Than you! Could you recommend any other/better model for my case?

Comment: K-Means is the standard non-supervised clustering method out there. It is easy to understand and implement. Finding a "better one" depends on the data you have. Take a look at [scikit-learn overview of clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods) and remember to take into account both time and memory complexity!